# Error:Class "X" contains illegal final field "Y"

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I am using Kotlin data class with Realm, Gson annotation for fetching Data from server.

**Problem:** When I run project in Android Studio it gives the following error:

```
Error:Class "VenderConfig" contains illegal final field "name".
```

I am learning  Kotlin so don't have much idea about that.

**My `VenderConfig` class is:**

```
@RealmClass
class VenderConfig(
        @SerializedName("name")
        val name: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("website")
        val wb_url: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("icon")
        val icon: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("logo")
        val logo: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("description")
        val description: String? = null,
        @PrimaryKey
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: Int? = null
) : RealmObject() {

}
```

I have also tried `open` keyword with the field and removed `data` keyword, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't the class be `open` for this to work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use `var` keyword to declare mutable properties. `val` stands for immutable (final) ones.

```
var name: String? = null
name = "Kotlin" // OK

val immutableName: String? = null
immutableName = "Java" // won't compile, val cannot be reassigned
```

*For more info: [Properties and Fields](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)*

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the class be **open**? (me-too ;)

@Realm-database: realm-java-3.1.0.zip
\examples\kotlinExample\src\main\kotlin\io\realm\examples\kotlin\model\Person.kt

```
    package io.realm.examples.kotlin.model

    import io.realm.RealmList
    import io.realm.RealmObject
    import io.realm.annotations.Ignore
    import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey

    // ... 
    // Furthermore, the class and all of the properties
    // must be annotated with open 
    // (Kotlin classes and methods are final by default).
    // 
    open class Person(

    ...

    ) : RealmObject() {
        // The Kotlin compiler generates standard getters and setters.
        // Realm will overload them and code inside them is ignored.
        // So if you prefer you can also just have empty abstract methods.
    }
```